# vb.net multiple threads Threads increasing the same Prograssbar or Integer

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

i am using multiple threads to do some processes and i want to display the total progress in a progressbar so How can i do the ProgressBar1.Increment(1) in a safe way?

```
Public Sub thread1process()
    For i = 0 To t1.Rows.Count - 1
        t1.Rows(i)("cname") = "Thread1"
        t1.Rows(i)("PD") = i
        t1.Rows(i)("PDP") = i
        t1.Rows(i)("TPD") = i
        t1.Rows(i)("TPDP") = i
        ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub thread2process()
    For i = 0 To t2.Rows.Count - 1
        t2.Rows(i)("cname") = "Thread2"
        t2.Rows(i)("PD") = i
        t2.Rows(i)("PDP") = i
        t2.Rows(i)("TPD") = i
        t2.Rows(i)("TPDP") = i
        ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    Next
End Sub
```

also how would i increase a public variable from multiple threads in the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i do the ProgressBar1.Increment(1) in a safe way?

You could use the [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method on the Form in order to marshal the call on the main UI thread.

> also how would i increase a public variable from multiple threads in the same time?

Use the [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

You want to ideally update the GUI on a different thread to your main. [Background worker thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) should work for you.